# Mongoose: Possible to use Schema Type Mixed and populate?

Tags: mongoose

How can I define a mixed schema in Mongoose as in

`member: {}`

but at the same time employ a populate as in

```
member: { 
          vip: { 
                    type:mongoose.Schema-Types.ObjectId, ref: 'importantPersons', default: '12983198312312e78271'
               }
        }
```

When I do the latter and I instantiate a Model from this Schema and fill it with different values not defined in member schema, they will not stick, e.g. get not into the instantiated model when console-logging it out.